# How can I know if the input is alphabet or not? I must only accept letters and a dot for middle initial in name

Tags: c, arrays, string, fgets

How can I check if the input is alphabet? I must only accept letters and 1 dot for middle initial in name. How can I do it?

Here is my code:

```
void name_check()
{
    printf(LEV3"Name:\t");
    int y=0;
    if ((fgets(name[i], LEN, stdin))==0)
    {
        y = atoi(name[i]);
        if((isalpha(y))!=0)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            printf(LEV3"ERROR: Invalid Name. Name should consist of letters only.\n");
            name_check();
            printf("\n");
        }   
    }
}
```

Help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this below code:

```
int  j=0;
if ((fgets(name[i], LEN, stdin))==0)
        {
           // y = atoi(name[i]);
            while( j<strlen(name[i]) && (isalpha(name[i][j]) || name[i][j]=='.'))
                j++;

            if(j==strlen(name[i]));
            {
            //....
            }
            else 
            {
                printf(LEV3"ERROR: Invalid Name. Name should consist of letters only.\n");
                name_check();
                printf("\n");
            }   
        }
```

Comment: Um... [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) returns NULL only if it *failed*. So assuming it does not, *nothing* inside that if-block is going to execute. And loop conditions repeatedly executing `strlen()` a bad practice that should be broken earlier and not later.

Comment: @WhozCraig yes there is only one possibility when fgets fails and statements inside if block would not effect Much. sorry, i did not noticed that one.Need to use this  **while((fgets(name[i], LEN, stdin))!=NULL)** instead of **if((fgets(name[i], LEN, stdin))==0)** and

Comment: @Gangadhar: Please *edit* your answer to correct this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Read using `fgets()` and `sscanf()` to parse.

```
char buffer[300];
if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) == NULL) {
  printf("EOF\n"); // TBD handle EOF or I/O error
}
else {
  char First[100];
  char Middle[100];
  char Dot[2];
  char Last[100];
  int n;
  n = sscanf(buffer, " %99[A-Za-z]  %98[A-Za-z]%1[. ]  %99[A-Za-z]", First, Middle, Dot, Last);
  if (4 != n) {
    printf("Oops %d\n", n); // TBD handle syntax error
  }
  if (Dot[0] == '.')
    strcat(Middle, Dot);
  printf("%s %s %s\n", First, Middle, Last);
}
```